# Unable to use form validations when adding rows with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to submit a laravel form

Using a button I am adding dynamic rows with javascript. Code is

```
<input type="button" value="Add Particular" onClick="addRow('dataTable')"/>
```

Laravel Form:

```
<table class="table" id="dataTable">
<tr>
<td>
    <label for="Fee Category" > Fee Category * </label>
    <select name='CategoryID[]' rows='5' class='CategoryID' code='{$CategoryID}' 
                            class='select2 '  requred  ></select> 
</td>
<td>
    <label for="Amount">Amount *</label>
    {{ Form::text('amount[]', $row['amount'],array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'', 'required'=>'true', 'parsley-type'=>'number'   )) }} 

</td>
<td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
</tr>
```

Javascript Functions to add & Delete Rows:

```
        function addRow(tableID)
    {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        if(rowCount<5)
        {
            var row = table.insertRow (rowCount);
            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
            for(var i=0;i<colCount; i++)
            {
                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                newcell.innerHTML= table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Max Reached")
        }
    }

function deleteRow(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

I am unable to use Laravel form validation error results to newly added rows. Its working fine on hard coded form rows. Please help

Also How can I keep minimum of one row. Currently delete button deletes all rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an onchange event on every field even in the dynamic ones, they will call the validator as sson as they are changed so the user knows in no time if it was a valid entrance.

I wrote this code in a hurry, color example is applied, new line example is too, remove is added too, empty box on focus is applied too and all other things asked.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

/**
A dynamic name is assigned to a new field created.
*/ 
var id=0;
var dbq="\"";

/************************* addRow function end ******************************************/
 function addRow(count)
 { 
 /**
 Decide what fieldset is going to host the row
 */
    var myFieldset='fieldset2';
    var section='2';
    if(count==4){
        myFieldset='fieldset1';
        var organisationID = id++;
        var positionID = id++;
       var section=''
        }  
 /**
    Create ids
 */
    divID = id++;
    nameID = id++;
    emailID = id++;  
 /**
    The row will be hosted in a div
 */
    var myDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
         myDiv.setAttribute("id", divID);  
 /**
    Create the text boxes
 */
    myDivInnerHTML=
    '<input type=text name=name'+section+'[]'+' value=Name id='+nameID+
    ' onFocus='+dbq+'emptyTheBox('+nameID+');'+dbq+ 
    ' onkeyup='+dbq+'changeInputColor('+nameID+');'+dbq+ 
    ' onBlur='+dbq+'fieldValidator('+nameID+');'+dbq+
    ' style='+dbq+'color:#66634F;'+dbq+' >'+   

    '<input type=text name=email'+section+'[]'+' value=Email id='+emailID+
    ' onFocus='+dbq+'emptyTheBox('+emailID+');'+dbq+
    ' onkeyup='+dbq+'changeInputColor('+emailID+');'+dbq+    
    ' onBlur='+dbq+'fieldValidator('+emailID+');'+dbq+  
    ' style='+dbq+'color:#66634F;'+dbq+'>' ;
 /**
    Decide if we need 4 or 2 boxes
 */
    if(count==4)
    myDivInnerHTML=myDivInnerHTML+
    '<input type=text name=organisation'+section+'[]'+' value=Organisation id='+organisationID+
    ' onFocus='+dbq+'emptyTheBox('+organisationID+');'+dbq+
    ' onkeyup='+dbq+'changeInputColor('+organisationID+');'+dbq+ 
    ' onBlur='+dbq+'fieldValidator('+organisationID+');'+dbq+  
    ' style='+dbq+'color:#66634F;'+dbq+' >'+   

    '<input type=text name=position'+section+'[]'+' value=Position id='+positionID+
    ' onFocus='+dbq+'emptyTheBox('+positionID+');'+dbq+
    ' onkeyup='+dbq+'changeInputColor('+positionID+');'+dbq+ 
    ' onBlur='+dbq+'fieldValidator('+positionID+');'+dbq+ 
    ' style='+dbq+'color:#66634F'+dbq+'>' ;
 /**
    Create a button to remove the row too.
 */
    myDivInnerHTML=myDivInnerHTML+
    '<input type=button class="remove" value="Remove"  onClick='+dbq+'removeDiv('+divID+','+ myFieldset +');'+dbq+' >';   
 /**
    Add the div-row to the fieldset
 */
    myDiv.innerHTML = myDivInnerHTML; 
    document.getElementById(myFieldset).appendChild(myDiv);      
 }
/************************* addRow function end ******************************************/

 /**
    Change the color of the text being entered
 */
function changeInputColor(caller){   
    document.getElementById(caller).style.color = 'black';
}

 /**
    Remove a row on demand
 */
function removeDiv(divID, myFieldset){ 
    myFieldset.removeChild(document.getElementById(divID)); 
}

 /**
    Empty the box on initial click
 */
function emptyTheBox(caller)
{
    var val=document.getElementById(caller).value;
    if(val=='Name' || val=='Email' || val=='Organisation' || val=='Position'  ) 
        document.getElementById(caller).value='';  
 }
/**
    Display a message
 */
 function echo(message)
 {
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML="<h3>"+message+"</h3>";   
 }


/**********************Validates a single field, return false on fail************************/
function fieldValidator(caller)
 {  
    var error='';
    /** 
        Identify the field (if it is email, name etc) by getting the first character
        which is always the same,also get its value and full name
    */  
    var currentFieldCategory = document.getElementById(caller).name.charAt(0);
    var currentFieldValue = document.getElementById(caller).value; 
    var currentField = document.getElementById(caller);

    /** 
        Check for empty value
    */
     if(currentFieldValue == '')
     {
        echo('Please fill the data!');currentField.focus(); 
        return 'Please fill the data!';
     }  
    /** 
        Check if default value left behind  
    */  
    if(currentFieldValue.toLowerCase()=="name" || currentFieldValue.toLowerCase()
    =="email" || currentFieldValue.toLowerCase()=="organisation" ||
    currentFieldValue.toLowerCase()=="position" )  
    { 
        echo('Please check you entry, default data left behind!');currentField.focus();   
        return 'Please check you entry, default data left behind!';
    }    
    /** 
        Validate the NAME field
    */   
    if(currentFieldCategory=='n')
    {
        if(currentFieldValue.match(/^[ |'|-]/)||!(/^[a-zA-Z- ']*$/.test(currentFieldValue))
            || currentFieldValue.length<4 || currentFieldValue.length>70)  
        {
            echo('Non valid name found!');currentField.focus();   
            return 'Non valid name found!';
        }//inner if
    }//outer if
    /** 
        Validate a non empty EMAIL name field
    */  
    if(currentFieldCategory=='e')
    {
        var atpos=currentFieldValue.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos=currentFieldValue.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=currentFieldValue.length) 
        {
            echo('Non valid email found!');currentField.focus();   
            return 'Non valid email found!';
        }//inner if 
    }//outer if
    /** 
        Validate a non empty ORGANIZATION name field
    */  
    if(currentFieldCategory=='o')
    {
        if(currentFieldValue.length<2 || currentFieldValue.length>50)
        {
            echo('Use at least 2 letters and less than 50 for your organisation.'); 
            currentField.focus();           
            return 'Use at least 2 letters and less than 50 for your organisation.';        
        }//inner if  
    }//outer if 
    /** 
        Validate a non empty POSITON name field
    */  
    if(currentFieldCategory=='p')
    {
        if(currentFieldValue.length<7 || currentFieldValue.length>40)
        {
            echo('Use at least 7 letters and less than 40 to describe your position.');
            currentField.focus(); 
            return 'Use at least 7 letters and less than 40 to describe your position.';            
        }//inner if 
    }//outer if     
    /** 
        Now on success do the rest
    */  
    document.getElementById(caller).style.backgroundColor = '#FF9900';  
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML="";
    return true;
 }
 /*****************fieldValidator ***function ends*****************************************/



/*******************************************************************************************/
function finalValidator()
{
    /**
        Get the form object
    */  
    var myForm=document.getElementById('booking').elements;
    /**
        Check if the form has no rows, for now 3 indicates no rows,
        BE CAREFULL it might change if more buttons added,
        just alert the length to see.
    */  
    if(myForm.length==3)
        return false; 
    /**
        Iterate through the form for all fields
    */  
    for(var i = 0; i < myForm.length; i++)
        {   
            //If it is a text field validate it
            if(myForm[i].type=='text')
            {
                var validation = fieldValidator(myForm[i].id);
                if(validation!==true)
                {
                    echo (validation);
                    return false;//prevent submit
                }//validation if
            }//field type if 
        }//for loop   
}//function
/*******************************************************************************************/


</script> 

</head>
<body bgcolor=gray>

<div id="add-buttons"><span class="add" onclick="addRow(4);"><input type="button" class="button" value="Add Waged Person"></span><span class="add" onclick="addRow(2);"><input type="button" class="button" value="Add Unwaged Person"></span></div>


<div id="message"  ></div>
<div id="form-wrap">
<form method="post" name="booking" id="booking" action="bookingengine.php">
    <fieldset id="fieldset1">
        <div class="subtitle">Waged/Organisation Rate</div>
    </fieldset> 

    <fieldset  id="fieldset2">
        <div class="subtitle">Unwaged Rate</div>
    </fieldset>

   <!-- return finalValidator will allow submit only if fields are validated-->
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"  onClick="return finalValidator();" 
     value="Submit booking" class="submit-button" /></p>
</form> 


</body>
</html>
```

Validation added. The array and the color things are a bit trivial and you should show what effort you have done here your self.It is interesting to be involved only when you see the will on someone.

Answer (score 1):

for adding the row

```
function addRow(tableID)
    {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        if(rowCount<5)
        {
            var row = table.insertRow (rowCount);
            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
            for(var i=0;i<colCount; i++)
            {
                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                newcell.innerHTML= table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Max Reached")
        }
    }
```

to delete the particular row use the `rowIndex` to find the particular row and `deleteRow` to delete the particular row from the table

```
function deleteRow(btn) {
      var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
      document.getElementById("dataTable").deleteRow(row);
    }
```

for the valdation use the `parentNode` and `childNodes` because they will work on DOM